# Java Class reference

Tags: java, class, reference

```
Animal remove = te.head;
te.head.size = 8;
te.head = null;



System.out.print(remove.getSize()); //gets 8, not null
```

for Class Animal

```
class Animal{
    int size;

    public Animal(int data) {
       this.size = data; 
    }

    public int getSize() {
       return this.size;
    }
}
```

I tired hard to understand that variable "remove" referenced "te.head" and when using the method "getSize()", returns 8, not null.

I am java beginner, Please explain why "remove.geSize()" does not return null error. it should be null, right?

Comment: Can you add the code for the Animal class? There's noway to know what remove() unless the code is there.

Comment: @Scratte I added

Comment: `remove` has a reference to `te.head`, the original reference to `Animal` was nulled. But you have created a copy of the reference. That is `System.out.print(te.head);` would output `null`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but actually they are using same address, right? That's why when the variable is changed to 5 or any number, the "remove" also changed. So remove Should be also null - This is my point

Comment: @BongSi-Yoon In Java, unlike some other languages, you never actually have an instance of a class. You have a reference to an instance of a class. While you can null the reference, you cannot null the instance. The garbage collector **counts** the number of references to living instances.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it! @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

Explanations are inside the code:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creating one Animal and setting teHead to point to it
    Animal teHead = new Animal(9);  

    // setting a new reference to the same Animal
    // now there are two references pointing to the same Object
    Animal remove = teHead;         

    // Changing the content of the Animal
    teHead.size = 8;
    System.out.println(remove.getSize());

    // teHead is now not pointing anywhere. But remove is still pointing to Animal
    teHead = null;   
    System.out.println(remove.getSize());
    // Using teHead now will give a NullPointerException
//    System.out.print(teHead.getSize());

    remove = null;   // Now nothing is pointing to Animal

    // Using remove now will give a NullPointerException
//    System.out.print(remove.getSize());
  }
}
```